# Time difference using awk

Tags: time, awk

I am looking for a one-liner awk code to find the difference between a time and system date. The time format is like this: 16:13:04,699 I want the difference in minutes. I am not quite familiar with awk, I can calculate this difference by writing a script but want to do it in one line.

Thank you.

Comment: how to compare a timestamp without date with system date?

Comment: At first you need to get the current day month year, then you need to add that to your incomplete timestap, then you have to convert this string to the epoch, take the difference with the current system time, finally calculate the difference in minutes. I my opinion this cannot be done this easily with a one liner. If you already know how to do it, then use your script or show us, what you have done so far.

Comment: @Chris awk one liner can make it. as long as the given time has date too.

Comment: please edit your post to show you inputs and expected output. I mean system date = Nov 17 2011, 10:35 am, 'a time'= 16:13:04,699', expect output = ??? It's hard to code something against your current description of the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a one-liner:

```
awk -v 'time=16:13:04,699' -v "date=$(date +%H:%M:%S)" '
  function abs(x) {return x<0 ? -x : x}
  BEGIN {
    split(time, ary, /[:,]/); t_sec = 3600*ary[1] + 60*ary[2] + ary[3]
    split(date, ary, /:/);    d_sec = 3600*ary[1] + 60*ary[2] + ary[3]
    # output difference in minutes
    print abs(t_sec - d_sec)/60
  }
'
```